# how to export API data code into database code using Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I working with API data right now, I using request method to get API data, but when I want to put into database, it show **sql.getconnection is not a function** in terminal... sorry for silly question, I still new with coding

there's missing something important in my code?

this is my code:

```
var request = require('request');
const sql = require("./mysql.js");

var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': 'https://api.getgo.com/oauth/v2/token',
  'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'my encode',
    'Cookie': '*****'
  },
  form: {
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token': 'refresh token'
  }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {

  let json = JSON.parse(body);
    
  const {organizer_key, account_key, access_token, refresh_token} = json
  const akey = account_key;
  const okey = organizer_key;
  
    // console.log(`Organizer key: ${organizer_key}`);
    // console.log(`Account key: ${account_key}`);
    // console.log(json);
  sql.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
   var sql = `INSERT INTO credentialkey (accountKey, organizerKey) VALUES 
   (${akey}, ${okey})`;  
   connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {  
    if (err) throw err;  
    console.log("1 record inserted");  
   });
 });
});
```

and this is my database code for mysql:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

require('dotenv').config()
//var value = require('./request.js');

//console.log(value.okey);

const dbHost = process.env.DB_HOST;
const dbUser = process.env.DB_USER;
const dbPass = process.env.DB_PASS;
const dbData = process.env.DB_DATA;

//console.log(process.env.DB_DATA);

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: dbHost,
  user: dbUser,
  password: dbPass,
  database: dbData
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('connected');
})

module.exports = connection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.getConnection()` method is existed on [Pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections) object, not [Connection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#establishing-connections) object.

You can use `connection.query(sql)` directly since:

> a connection can also be implicitly established by invoking a query

So, you can change your code like below:

```js
var request = require('request');
const sql = require('./mysql.js');

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://api.getgo.com/oauth/v2/token',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    Authorization: 'my encode',
    Cookie: '*****',
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: 'refresh_token',
    refresh_token: 'refresh token',
  },
};

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
  let json = JSON.parse(body);

  const { organizer_key, account_key, access_token, refresh_token } = json;
  const akey = account_key;
  const okey = organizer_key;
  var sqlstr = `INSERT INTO credentialkey (accountKey, organizerKey) VALUES (${akey}, ${okey})`;
  sql.query(sqlstr, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('1 record inserted');
  });
});
```